# Developing IntelliJ IDEA plugin to interactively plot (JSON) data inside IDEA's tool window

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plot, intellij-plugin

I'm working on IntelliJ IDEA plugin that will display/plot data from a JSON file or some other similar data source. I have already tried multiple java 3d plotting libraries (Jzy3D, JFreeChart...), but I can't get them to work inside IDEA's tool window.

I tried using [Jzy3D](http://www.jzy3d.org/)'s regular api as well as their javafx api. With the former one, I was able to store plots as JPanel objects, but when I use these here:

```
public class PlotToolWindowFactory implements ToolWindowFactory {
    @Override
    public void createToolWindowContent(Project project, ToolWindow toolWindow) {
       PlotDemo plotDemo = new PlotDemo();
       ContentFactory contentFactory = ContentFactory.SERVICE.getInstance();
       // plotDemo.getContent() returns JPanel object containing a graph
       Content content = contentFactory.createContent(plotDemo.getContent(), "", false);
       toolWindow.getContentManager().addContent(content);
    }
}
```

I get `failed to init toolwindow PlotToolWindowFactory` error. I've been trying to fix this, but with no success.

Since I'm very new to IntelliJ plugin development I'm wondering if this can even work (as I imagined it) anyways? So I'm thinking not only about fixing this, but also about changing the library and the whole approach.

I have next requirements:

- plots need to be interactive,
- they need to work on Community edition of IDEA,
- no 3rd party API calls needed (as Google's charts API). It has to
  work offline, without sending any of my info to 3rd parties.

Does anyone have any recommendation for a library to use? Has there been anything similar done before (and is it possible to look at the source code)?

Do I have to add tool window event listener for every type of plot interactive action? Is content inside tool window static or does it refresh automatically?

Any other tips regarding this will be greatly appreciated as well!

Comment: Great work, but your question feels broad to me.  I don't know what "can't get them to work" looks like.  Perhaps a Java plotting library would be a better choice than JavaScript.

Comment: @duffymo thank you for the reply. I've updated the post with more detailed explanation.

Comment: Try searching/asking on this forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979